# Chart.js passing value data dynamic

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, chart.js

I am want to use data and level dynamic by ajax, so i am using as below but not working.

My ajax return data in `json_encode` of php.
My code is:

```
success: function (result) {
           result = JSON.parse(result);
           var labels = result['labels'];
           var data = result['data'];
           //console.log(data);
           var ctx = document.getElementById("chartbtc");
           var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: [labels],
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'Market Price (USD)',
                            data: [data],
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: true,
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: false
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

But chart is not generating:

Ajax result is:

```
{"labels":"13-Nov-2017, 14-Nov-2017, 15-Nov-2017, 16-Nov-2017, 17-Nov-2017, 18-Nov-2017, 19-Nov-2017, 20-Nov-2017, 21-Nov-2017, 22-Nov-2017, 23-Nov-2017, 24-Nov-2017, 25-Nov-2017, 26-Nov-2017, 27-Nov-2017, 28-Nov-2017, 29-Nov-2017, 30-Nov-2017, 01-Dec-2017, 02-Dec-2017, 03-Dec-2017, 04-Dec-2017, 05-Dec-2017, 06-Dec-2017, 07-Dec-2017, 08-Dec-2017, 09-Dec-2017, 10-Dec-2017, 11-Dec-2017, 12-Dec-2017","data":"6550.22, 6635.41, 7301.42, 7815.03, 7786.88, 7817.14, 8007.65, 8255.59, 8059.8, 8268.03, 8148.94, 8250.97, 8707.4, 9284.14, 9718.29, 9952.5, 9879.32, 10147.37, 10883.91, 11071.36, 11332.62, 11584.82, 11878.43, 13540.98, 16501.97, 16007.43, 15142.83, 14869.8, 16762.11, 17276.39"}
```

Comment: do you get any errors in your browser console? If you put a `console.log("testing");` just before `var myChart...` does it get printed?

Comment: testing is showing on console

Answer (score 2):

Since you have provided your ajax result, this will not work with the chart generation. In your case `result["labels"]` is a string and you are just making a list with 1 element which is the whole string(which is not valid for the `labels` property and will not work). What you should do is split the string, format it correctly and then supply it as a list to the `labels` property. Easiest way would be to use the `split()` function, and in your case you could split by `", "`. Although I would recommend to implement a better response if its possible (have it something like so: `{"labels": ["13-Nov-2017", "14-Nov-2017", ...]}`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Now i have updated ajax result, so please check question again. Thanks

Comment: @ShivSingh well you are still supplying just a single string. Do a `results["labels"].split(", ");` and that will give you the correct data structure/type to pass on to the `labels` property. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For the first time you can fill the chart with your own value, but when it is coming for dynamically appending data then you should remove the `canvas` element and regenerate it. So that your data will get appended dynamically on chart.

You can try something like this.

```
<canvas id="chartbtc" class="canvasChart"></canvas>

<script>

    dynamicDataAppendOnChart(labels, data); // On page loading you will be having your own data so you can pass them, or if you want that to be happen with ajax when page loading itself you can trigger the click event.

    $('#btnClick').trigger('click');

    // You will be calling the function with click event...
    $('#btnClick').on('click', function () {
        var data = '', labels = '';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            async: isAsync,
            success: function (result) {
               result = JSON.parse(result);
               labels = result['labels'];
               data = result['data'];
            }
        });
        dynamicDataAppendOnChart(labels, data); // Now you can call the function by passing labels and data
    });

    function dynamicDataAppendOnChart() {
        $('#chartbtc').remove();
        $('#appendTheCanvasElement').append('<canvas id="chartbtc" class="canvasChart"><canvas>'); // This would create new canvas element every time and removes the older one.
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chartbtc");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [labels],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Market Price (USD)',
                    data: [data],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: false
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.
Declare label and data as

```
var labels = result['labels'].split(","); // Return Array of Strings Of labels
var data =   JSON.parse("[" +  result['data'] + "]");// return array of data
```

Chage

```
labels: [labels],
data: [data],
```

to

```
labels: labels,
    data: data,
```

Because it already in array

Comment: Solved after split(",") to both labels and data